# WPF icon preloading

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, image, preloading

My application does a lot of work with currencies and so frequently makes use of 80-90 .ICO files I have as resources which are country flags, to represent each currency. Most screens use these and it seems a waste to keep reloading them for each use, especially given that when I use a datatemplate that has an IMG tag, it freezes the GUI or makes it very unperformant when loading these in ListViews etc.

Is there some way or design that's recommended in WPF whereby I can preload these images into the WPF application space so that whenever they are referenced, they are already cached and loaded globally so I only have to load them into memory once at application start, then every usage from then on in is lightning fast?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a app level ResourceDictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to place them into the Application.Resources in your xaml.

Those are loaded only once and accessible everywhere in your app.'

See [How to: Use Application Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746624.aspx) on msdn.

**EDIT:**
In your class where you bind your items too (class that contains `IconSelect`) you need to add an extra property.

```
public BitmapImage BitmapIconSelect
{
    get
    {
        return Application.Resources[IconSelect];
    }
}
```

And then bind to this property:

```
<Image Source="{Binding BitmapIconSelect, IsAsync=True, Mode=OneWay}" Width="20" Height="20" />
```

I wrote this code freehand, so I am not sure if it compiles but I hope you get my point.

Comment: I am using it from a Binding though in a datatemplate - how can I use static resources with a binding? <Image Source="{Binding IconSelect, IsAsync=True, Mode=OneWay}" Width="20" Height="20" />

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm still unsure how I can use resource dictionaries for this. To clarify, the bound property of the object being displayed, is a filename of a bitmap icon, ie USD.ico or GBP.ico - but this comes from the object property. At the moment its being bound as my comment above, but I don't see how using a {StaticResource tag helps me as surely then I have to explicitly set the name of the resource in the XAML, not have it come from a bound property at runtime, if that makes sense?